# Android: Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a column name as "source" in my table.
I m trying to delete all the entries which has source = testing.
I am doing it with the following code 
DB.delete(Dbhelper.getTestingTableName(), "source=" + testing, null);

but it always gives error :
no such column: testing: , while compiling: DELETE FROM TestingTable WHERE source=testing

But when I use the same command "DELETE FROM TestingTable WHERE source=testing" through abd sqlite3 it works perfectly... any reason???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use it in following way:

```
String wereClause = "source = ?";
String[] wereArgs = new String[]{testing.toString()};  //if testing is variable
DB.delete(Dbhelper.getTestingTableName(), wereClause, wereArgs);
```

Comment: in case if its working... maybe good its idea to accept answer ;)

Comment: hey woodshy u are correct...let me know how to accept the answer...not able to find the way to do so.

Comment: you should click on the check under "useful count" on left of the answer. It will become green. Thanks.